# Estimate a parameter that is not in a PDF, makes sense?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have been reading some posts about the proof of the invariance of MLE because I did not fully understood the proof given in Statistical inference by Casella Berger in the page 320.

My doubt is the following... if we want to estimate a parameter should not that parameter be in model? **The Maximum Likelihood Estimators method assumes that the parameter is explicity in the model.**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4c37.png) is the start of the proof and the transformation is $\eta=\tau(\theta)$.

[image: Here]

To be precise my question is, shouldn't

$$\text{L(}\eta|X)$$

be the function to maximize instead of the function $\text{L(}\theta|X)$?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter $\theta$ (which may be a scalar or vector), for the purposes of discussion, completely specifies the model in question.  For instance, we might say $$\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$$ for a normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  Or, if the variance is known, $\theta = \mu$.

Then any function of that parameter, say $\eta = \tau(\theta)$, might not be invertible, but it is still "in the model" in the sense that inference on $\eta$ is deterministically related to inference on $\theta$.  For instance, we could be interested in a discretization of $\theta$:  $$\eta = \lfloor \theta \rfloor,$$ where $\tau = \lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.  It's not invertible--if I told you I estimated $\hat\eta = 3$, all that tells you is that the corresponding estimate of $\theta$ is $\hat \theta \in [3, 4)$.  It is not required that we estimate $\theta$ itself.  We estimate what is of interest.

As for your other question, it must be $L^*(\eta \mid X)$, because this is the (induced) likelihood of $\eta$ with respect to the sample and is literally what we are seeking to maximize.

Let's put it another way.  Say that the parameter of interest was $\theta = \mu$ for a normal random variable with known variance $\sigma^2 = 1$.  We know that the sample mean is the MLE; $$\hat \theta = \bar X$$ maximizes the likelihood $L(\theta \mid X)$.

But what if I told you that the mean parameter $\mu$ is actually a transformation of an underlying parameter $\psi$, which I call "angle," and obeys the relationship $$\mu = \tan \psi?$$  Maybe you've never heard of such a parametrization, and all this time, you've been doing inference on $\mu$ directly.  You've constructed your likelihoods based on $\mu$.  Nothing was amiss.  And when you look at $L$, you're **not** looking at $L(\psi \mid X)$.

So why then, if we are talking about $\eta$, are you thinking the likelihood to be maximized in Theorem 7.2.10 should be $L(\theta \mid X)$ rather than $L^*(\eta \mid X)$?  All I have done in my example above is reason in the other direction--i.e., $\mu$ is $\eta$ and $\theta$ is $\psi$ in my example.